# Does Java support uniform access?

Tags: c#, java

I was wondering if Java supports uniform access. For example, in C# aCircle.radius might invoke a radius():float method or directly refer to a public field depending on the definition of the class. Is anyone know if it is the same for Java.

Thanks !

Comment: Why don't you try it? And `aCircle.radius` certainly won't invoke C# method. (It might invoke property getter, though, which has no equivalent in Java.)

Comment: svick: it seems to me that a property getter is indistinguishable from a method when discussing the uniform access principle - the only difference is in the syntax of the definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java does not have this. You can have a field and a method with the same name (that is, they live in different name spaces) and the only way the compiler can disambiguate which you want is that method calls must have parens.

Comment: Which would be ambiguous in C#, because you can have delegate fields that can look almost like a method.